# attaching a website name on image or picture

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Please is there any php script that I can attach my website name on a picture so that when users download any pictures or images from my site, my website name wil be attached there, just like how shutter stock did theirs. Please help! Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, we do not provide script recommendations here. Please see [ask] before asking a question.

Comment: try to play with php image functions and gd library

Answer (score 1):

You should use php [watermark](http://www.php.net/manual/en/image.examples-watermark.php) function.

Center positioned watermark

```
<?php
// Load the stamp and the photo to apply the watermark to
$stamp = imagecreatefrompng('stampimg.png');
$im = imagecreatefrompng('mainimage.png');

// Set the margins for the stamp and get the height/width of the stamp image
$marge_right = 10;
$marge_bottom = 10;
$sx = imagesx($stamp);
$sy = imagesy($stamp);

$imgx = imagesx($im);
$imgy = imagesy($im);
$centerX=round($imgx/2);
$centerY=round($imgy/2);

// Copy the stamp image onto our photo using the margin offsets and the photo 
// width to calculate positioning of the stamp. 
imagecopy($im, $stamp, $centerX, $centerY, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp));

// Output and free memory
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```